# How to stop multiple post requests when user rapidly presses a submit button

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am using flask and wtforms and if a user wants to rapidly press the submit button to send 10 or 15 post requests to the database the app will currently process all of the POST requests which is not cool.  Is there a way to only process one post request for however many times the user should press the submit button within a certain time frame of the first submission, maybe?  How do you handle this situation?

Comment: Why don't you use Javascript to disable the button for a certain amount of time and enable it again?

Comment: Create some sort of lock when you start processing a request.  Do not process any new requests that would acquire the same lock until you have finished the original request.  How you create and manage the lock is something for which you have a bunch of options.

Comment: @larsks alright, do you happen to know of an option for flask?   Probably a good idea to disable the button also.